# batch FOR /F and space in file/pathname and usage of token?

Tags: svn, batch-file, svnlook

I am using a batch file to update only those files that have changed in my SVN repository. This is a part of my batch file:

```
SET CHANGES=svnlook changed c:\myrepository
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2" %%a IN (`%CHANGES%`) DO (echo %%a)
```

I only get *dok* instead of *dok version1.txt* and I guess thats because of the space. How must I change the code to get the filename even if there is a space? Is that because of the tokens or where does it cut the name?

The output of svnlook looks like:

*D   Testprojekt/trunk/dok - Kopie (2).txt

D   Testprojekt/trunk/dok - Kopie (3).txt

D   Testprojekt/trunk/dok - Kopie (4).txt*

So I am using tokens=2 to only get the path (Testprojekt/trunk/dok - Kopie (2).txt) and not the action (D=deleted for example).

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please edit the question and add a sample of raw svnlook's output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,*" %%a IN (`%CHANGES%`) DO (echo %%b)
```

This assigns the first token to %a and all subsequent ones to the next letter i.e. %b

Comment: Yeah, thats a start, I now get the path in a correct way...give me some secs to test further.

Comment: Dammit, you got the answer while I was doing some research xD

Answer (score 2):

With this output:

```
D Testprojekt/trunk/dok - Kopie (2).txt
D Testprojekt/trunk/dok - Kopie (3).txt
D Testprojekt/trunk/dok - Kopie (4).txt
```

... you can try this:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1*" %%a IN (`%CHANGES%`) DO (
    echo %%b
)
```

The `tokens=1*` bit means:

1. Store first token into %%a (i.e. `D`)
2. Store the rest of the line into %%b